# Kendo ui treeView Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, kendo-treeview

I'm using Kendo UI `TreeView` and I enabled the `dragAndDrop` option. When I perform a drag and drop, the node is well moved by in the text I have :

```
function ( value ) { return access( this, function( value ) { return value === undefined ? jQuery.text( this ) : this.empty().each( function() { if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) { this.textContent = value; } } ); }, null, value,
```

The images below show the case :

#### Before drag and drop :

[image: Before]

#### After moving a node

[image]

What am I missing ?

Thank you !

Comment: I guess you're using a template to format your items... What is your template code?

Comment: You are right Shai. My template is : `// template: "#= item.text #"`

Comment: Did you override the `dragend` or `drop` events of the `TreeView`?

Comment: Overriding them no but I use the callback functions to emit events in my angular 2 app.